# Windows event show network adapter change Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a windows eventid to show when a network adapter gateway setting was changed ?

Comment: Great anecdote.  What do you want from us?  If you don't like your VPS provider then use a different one.

Comment: I wasnt having a go at my hosting provider, more trying to distinguish if a server had been compromised or the hosting provider simply made a configuation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your case it also means changing the IP, then system even-id 4200 if the IP Helper service (iphlpsvc) is running.

> Isatap interface isatap.{8EC28501-0157-4458-A5D3-79FF79FA0C02} with address fe80::5efe:192.168.1.1 has been brought up.